# Create valid Time from integer with built-in function

Tags: r

Is there way to create `8:46:01` from integer `84601` without using modulo operations in R ? something like format with mask in another languages : `format(84600, "HHMMSS")` ? Otherwise modulo devision is needed and some messy formulas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
format(strptime("084601","%H%M%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
```

works, but you have to make sure that you have a two-digit hour, for example:

```
x <- "84601"
```

Put a zero in front of any 5-digit numeric strings:

```
xx <- gsub("([0-9]{5})","0\\1",x)
```

(or, as @Frank says in a comment, `sprintf("%06d", x)` will work for integers ...)

Convert:

```
format(strptime(xx,"%H%M%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
```

(if you don't `format()` you'll get a date-time string with the current date filled in ...)

Comment: Assuming the OP starts with an integer (as they say), they could also add the leading zero like `sprintf("%06d", 84601L)`

Answer (score 3):

Just treat it as a string:

```
x <- 84601
# index from end in case of extra hours digit
y <- paste0(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-4), ':', 
            substr(x, nchar(x)-3, nchar(x)-2), ':', 
            substr(x, nchar(x)-1, nchar(x)))
y
# [1] "8:46:01"
```

Or with regex:

```
y <- gsub('(.?.)(..)(..)', '\\1:\\2:\\3', x)
y
# [1] "8:46:01"
```

Or with `format` (formatting numbers, not time):

```
y <- format(x, big.mark = ':', big.interval = 2L)
y
# [1] "8:46:01"
```

If you need an actual time class, `chron::times` is nice:

```
chron::times(y)
# [1] 08:46:01
```

Comment: An alternative to chron is ITime from data.table, like `data.table::as.ITime(sprintf("%06d",x), "%H%M%S")`